# Does linux "clock()" function count in "sleep" time of a process?

Tags: linux, function, time, process, clock

I called "sleep" functions, but seems not really counted, like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    clock_t t1=clock();
    sleep(2);
    clock_t t2=clock();
    cout<<t2-t1<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It prints a very small number of millisecond time interval between 2 "clock()" calls. I expected that it should report 2,000,000.

Is my guess correct? man page doesn't specify any answer to my question. Is there a better function to get the time elapsed between 2 lines of code?

Comment: use gettimeofday()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clock(3)` doesn't return seconds, it returns the number of seconds used, divided by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` (value 1000000).

In C++, you probably want to use

```
auto t1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
sleep(2)
auto t2 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
auto duration = t2 - t1;
std::cout << duration.count() << endl;
```

Don't forget to compile with `-std=c++11`